# move textInput element to a separate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, native-base

I have a screen where I use this :

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

          <Item rounded style={styles.inputItem}>
            <Icon
              name="search"
              size={moderateScale(18)}
              color="#bdbdbd"
              style={styles.icon}
            />
            <Input
              autoFocus={true}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              style={styles.inputField}
              placeholder="Friend Search"
              keyboardType="default"
              onChangeText={(text: string) => {
                setSearchText(text);
              }}
            />
          </Item>
```

Instead of using the Input element on my current screen, I want to turn it into a reusable component. Something like this:

```
type SearchInputProps = {
  handleChange?: any;
};

export const SearchInput: React.FunctionComponent<SearchInputProps> = (handleChange) => {
  return (
    <Item rounded style={styles.inputItem}>
      <Icon name='search' size={moderateScale(18)} color="#bdbdbd" style={styles.icon}/>
      <Input
        autoFocus={true}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        style={styles.inputField}
        placeholder="Friend Search"
        onChangeText={()=>handleChange}
      />
    </Item>
  );
};
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to make the `onChangeText` work such that the `const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');` value from the main screen can be set over there. Is it even possible?

I tried to create a snack expo here but I am unable to install native base https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/curious-bubblegum

Edit:
Managed to resolve the type error but still don't know how to pass `setSearchText` while calling the component.

```
type SearchInputProps = React.PropsWithRef<{
  handleChange?: any;
}>;
export const FieldInput = React.forwardRef<Input, SearchInputProps>(
  ({ handleChange }) => {
    return (
      <Item rounded style={styles.inputItem}>
        <Icon
          name="search"
          size={moderateScale(18)}
          color="#bdbdbd"
          style={styles.icon}
        />
        <Input
          autoFocus={true}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          style={styles.inputField}
          placeholder="Friend Search"
          keyboardType="default"
          onChangeText={handleChange}
        />
      </Item>
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Which functionalities of the shared `Input` you want to control from consumer components?

Comment: I just want to be able to pass something like ```setSearchText(text)```while calling it. Such that I can set the state on the main screen using this component. @im_tsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a reusable `Input` component by containing common behavior inside the component and then exposing the APIs to consumer component through props. Here is a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/LVvrWBzmX) example. Please check the `Input` component inside components folder.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput as RnTextInput, View } from 'react-native';

const Input = ({label, onFocus, ...rest}) => {
  const [isFocussed, setIsFocussed] = useState(false);

  const handleFocus = () => {
    setIsFocussed(true);
    onFocus && onFocus();
  };

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, isFocussed && styles.inputFocused]}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>{label}</Text>
      <RnTextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        {...rest}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    margin: 5,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#d3d3d3',
  },
  label: {
    color: 'red',
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    fontSize: 16,
    paddingLeft: 10,
  },
  inputFocused: {
    borderBottomColor: 'blue'
  }
})

export default Input;
```

Then use the component like this:

```
<Input
  label="Enter Name"
  onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
  onFocus={handleOnFocus}
  placeholder="Enter some value"
  value={value}
/>
```

Note: I have used React Native inbuilt `TextInput` but as per my initial impression `native-base`'s `Input` has same API as RN `TextInput`.

Comment: Could you please try to modify this according to the native base input example I gave? Would be really helpful.

Comment: I haven't used `native-base` before. So if you can provide a working example of the Snack I can try.

Comment: What are you using btw? Expo or RN cli?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you aren't invoking your function correctly. Change your `onChangeText` line from:

```
onChangeText={()=>handleChange}
```

to:

```
onChangeText={handleChange}
```

or:

```
// Use this if you need to pass extra parameters from the child (SearchInput) component. 
onChangeText={(event) => handleChange(event, <extra params>)}
```

Comment: Changing to onChangeText={handleChange} gives me TypeErrors ```Type 'PropsWithChildren<{ handleChange?: any; }>' is not assignable to type '(text: string) => void'```But anyhow, how will I pass```setSearchText(text)```while calling it?

Comment: @Jnl your typing is not correct; `handleChange` is a function therefore its typing should be, for example, something like `handleChange?: () => void` or `handleChange?: (event: React.ChangeEvent) => void` (depending on the actual signature of `handleChange`)

Comment: I managed to resolve the type error by adding ```ref``` but I still don't know how to use the component to ```setSearchText```from a different screen.Could you see the updated qs? @secan